# Ruby on Rails: Save objects and attributes of model to another table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, callback

I have 2 tables. For example "Fruits" and "Food" When I create a new entry for the Fruits table with the corresponding model, how do I save objects and attributes of this one to the other table called All?

Or easier: How to update another table when saving a new entry?

i need something like "update value where id=x"

Comment: I read your other comment, and if you are totally new to ruby on rails, I strongly suggest you to complete this tutorial : http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book . Basically, you will be building a Twitter clone with a bunch of rails features, and you will learn the quick way how to make good rails applications.

Comment: had another tutorial for the start

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do something like this :

```
class Fruits < ActiveRecord::Base

    after_save :update_the_all_table

    private

        def update_the_all_table
            allobject = All.find(self.id)
            allobject.someattribute = self.someattribute # self is the fruit
            allobject.save
        end

end
```

Just so you know, you can also do the following if you don't want to write the "private" !

```
class Fruits < ActiveRecord::Base

    after_save { |fruit|
        allobject = All.find(fruit.id)
        allobject.someattribute = fruit.someattribute
        allobject.save
    }

end
```

Comment: yeah, read all about possible callbacks at : http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

Comment: didnt have to use the "private" on another medthod, do i have to use it and where exactly? right before the method or at the first lines of the model?

Comment: but what is better? before_save or after_save?

Comment: when private is declared, the following methods are all private. it is not necessary to make it work, it's just a best practice to hide methods that should only be used inside the model.

Comment: That depends on your need. I'd say in your case it does not really matter, as the validations occur before both of those callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) to perform actions on events like save.

Be wary about duplicating data, if you are just trying to create a table containing all the same information as other tables you may just need to query your data differently.

Comment: i alrerady know this but how can i access the model for the other table? i need something like "update value where id=x"

Comment: @Daniel Ruf: are you unable to use ActiveRecord for the other table for some reason?

Comment: no, but i need an example how i can do this like in mysql with update ... where ... like ...  im a bit confused, writing a whole existing app new in some days as a bloody newbie to ruby on rails but working directly with scaffolding, activerecord (which i didnjt hear before but i know now) is not so easy at the beginning and also adding many many custom methods

Answer (score 0):

The best practice in this case is using [observers](https://github.com/rails/rails-observers).

1) Add to your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'rails-observers'
```

2) Run:

```
bundle install
```

3) Create new file `app/models/fruit_observer.rb`:

```
class FruitObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
  def after_save(fruit)
    # Any actions with other models and tables must stay here.
    # Example:
    All.create(
      name: fruit.name,
      entitable_type: fruit.class.to_s,
      entitable_id: fruit.id
    )
  end
end
```

4) Add to your `application.rb`:

```
config.active_record.observers = :fruit_observer
```

5) Run server/console and check this out!